# Adjust margins (padding) between Editor windows

Tags: interface

I'd like to add a few pixels of padding between the Editors to make it easier to resize them. I believe there is a 3 pixel range to get the "double arrow cursor" for resizing. Apparently I am not coordinated enough to consistently place my cursor with that kind of precision. Is there any way to increase these margins through scripting, perhaps by modifying an existing script in the directory? Obviously this is doable on some level, but aside from getting into the source code or too deep into the data structure, is this a reasonable task for a novice programmer to accomplish?

This is what I'm shooting for...
[image]

Comment: I don't *think* this is possible without diving into the C source, but this would a nice option to have. Perhaps even if only the area where the mouse changes into the double arrow is increased, without adding visual padding

Comment: I got curious about this, and ended up looking around in the source code. I haven't tried anything, but the stuff around line `1166` in `source/blender/editors/interface/interface_panel.c` looks relevant. That said, questions about the C source are [considered off-topic here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/225/599).

Comment: Gotcha. I'm probably not qualified to monkey around in c so I guess I'll just have to live with it for now. Not such a big deal, but one of those little glitches in the Matrix that makes me swear under my breath every once in a while. But hey thanks for digging into that for me. I really appreciate it.  Maybe if I'm feeling adventurous or really bored I'll have a look at that code... Ok so I looked over the "off-topic" link. What's protocol? Shall I just delete the question?... Anyhow, thanks again. Have a good one.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you are more interested in solutions that *don't* involve the C source (such as python). As such, it seems like a perfectly on-topic question to me (though I suspect the answer is "not possible"). I thought I'd mention that C questions are off-topic, lest I give the wrong impression by jumping into the C myself.

Comment: Not spacing between windows, but you can adjust some of the spacing variables on Linux at least via `ctypes` hack - https://gitlab.com/snippets/14620

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do this without diving pretty deeply into the source :-/ It'd certainly be nice to make the borders wider, but we don't have that kind of access to the UI with Python.